# Samba: how to share?

Tags: samba, solaris, windows

I ask for a little explanation, if possible.
What are steps needed to share a unix dir with windows server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[THIS](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/) official guide is as good a one as I've ever found.